# Internal server error when returning an array or list with spring boot REST on Weblogic server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, weblogic-10.x

I am hosting a spring boot application(spring-boot-web-starter) on weblogic (v10.3.6)

I am trying to implement a simple REST api. Returning strings, ints etc works fine. When I try to return an array or a list using following code:

```
@GetMapping("/foo")
public String[] foo() {
    String[] arr = { "foo", "foo2" };
    return arr;
}
```

I get following error:

> 500 Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from
>   fulfilling the request.

1. The code works locally on embedded tomcat, when I upload application to the server I get the error instead.
2. I am unable to see the error/exception that is being thrown trough logs, as spring boot logging does not work on the server (it works perfectly fine locally, but on server no file is created, perhaps a problem with access rights)
3. I assume it has something to do with JSON serialisation. The server uses Java version 1.6, though I was unable to find out what could be the reason of the error.

EDIT: I am unable to return objects other than string as well. Only the basic Java types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the error by overriding Jackson version provided by Spring with version 2.6.7 (the last release compatibile with java 1.6)

Comment: upgrade your java version to java 8, then no need to use jackson jar

Comment: weblogic 10.3.6 enforces java 1.6

Comment: ohk, sorry i am not aware of weblogic